# Add a ceiling access panel above shower valve area for future plumbing access?

Tags: access-panel

is it a stupid idea to add a ceiling access panel on the bathroom ceiling above the shower valve /drain area for future plumbing access? Is a plastic one ok or metal ones are better?

Comment: I Like access panels and try to put them in where they won’t look bad, I am not sure about in the ceiling though. How is ceiling access going to help for the valve?

Comment: its for the bathroom upstairs. but some people said access panels allow the moisture and steam in the shower air going to the ceiling plenum. Is it a problem?  is this a good product: Oatey 34044 Access Panel

Comment: I'm a fan of access panels too and have installed them when making repairs. I'm not sure I would preemptively add one "just in case" especially above a shower because of the moisture.

Comment: That panel doesn’t say if it is sealed , I would agree that you would want it to be sealed since it is inside the shower. For showers I usually put one at the valve and another one at the floor level so I can get to the drain. This is on the outside of the shower sometimes in a hallway or in a closet. I usually use Sheetrock and trim , no need to purchase anything special. If in an obvious location like in a hallway where I had to replace a valve I have made it look like a ladder but only the bottom and middle sections come out. One of my renters asked if we could add more then put photos in

Answer (score 1):

Access panels installed in hidden locations like under cabinets or in a closet can be a great idea, but I wouldn't put one in a visible location until its needed.  There are repair panels that are made to be easy to install in a drywall hole cut in drywall.  You may never need it, so looking a that panel until you do seems extreme.

Plastic would be better in a damp location because metal will almost always rust over time even if it starts with what seems like a very good painted finish.  Even if you don't mind the look of the panel the next owner is going to be very suspicious of why the panel is there, and they will not like the look of it.